# Round does not accept argument type(Int)

Tags: swift, uint32

I'm trying to create my app about a math test as I come to division. I know that I can't create repeating infinite decimals, and I must keep the numbers random. So after I generated the numbers out of arc4random_uniform, I'm trying to use the round function. But it said

> Cannot find an overload for round that accepts argument type (Int)

How do I fix this?

Here's my code:

```
 var randomNumber:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(999)
 var randomNumber2:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(999)
 // 1000 is my maximum number for now.
 randomNumber += 1
 randomNumber2 += 1
 if operation.text == "/" {
     if randomNumber < randomNumber2 {
         var between:UInt32 = 1000 - randomNumber2
         randomNumber = randomNumber2 + arc4random_uniform(between - 1)
         // making sure that randomNumber is not smaller than randomNumber2,
         // therefore all results are positive.
     }
     var answer:Int = round(Int(randomNumber)/Int(randomNumber2))
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a `Float` value to `round` since it doesn't have prototypes using `Int` value:

```
var answer = round(Float(randomNumber)/Float(randomNumber2))
```

Comment: Will the result end up being an integer or a float?

Comment: It will be return a Float

Comment: Could I make it an int or at least leave only one decimal place?

Comment: It's up to you, depending of which precision do you need. Your value will be more precise if you keep it as a Float.

Comment: How do I make it an int?

Comment: `var answer: Int = round(Float(randomNumber)/Float(randomNumber2))`

Comment: That brings up the same problem